запустить скрипт из подмодуля из action.yml
Как запустить скрипт находящийся в подмодуле из action.yml?
такой вариант не работает:
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v4
  with:
    submodules: true

- name: Run script
  run: submodule/./script.sh
  shell: bash


Точка не нужна: submodule/script.sh. Ну и нужно смотреть лог сборки, там должно быть написано, что пошло не так.

@insolor github не может найти скрипт
